# Is it possible to create a mobile agent that uses Node.js?

Tags: node.js, distributed-computing, distributed, distributed-system

My aim is to create a mobile agent written in Node.js that will perform data collection on each node that is part of the mobile agent platform. If any anomalous events are detected then this is reported back to the control server. The mobile agent will follow a predefined path, saving its state and transferring to another nodes once its task is complete. Are there any frameworks or existing projects that would be suitable for this?

The Java Aglet project is similar to my needs however is obviously only available for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there was no current solution/package, I have created and now maintain the [mobile-agent-platform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-agent-platform) NPM package.

"A JavaScript Mobile Agent Platform that allows an agent to migrate across a network. A `Supervisor` node dispatches the `Agent` which can then autonomously move between `Worker` nodes, carrying/transferring its state and methods to the new node."

Note: the stack and program counter cannot be transferred due to limitations within Node.js.